# How Would I Add a Date To Microsoft Access?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am having issues adding dates/times to Microsoft Access, this is my code:

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "insert into DailyLog (EmployeeID,BusNumber,RouteID,DestinationID,ActivityID,Date,MilesDriven,GasInGallons,Comments) values('"+ employee.SelectedValue + "','" + bus.SelectedValue + "','" + route.SelectedValue + "','" + dest.SelectedValue + "','" + activity.SelectedValue + "','" + theDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + miles.Value + "','" + gas.Value + "','" + comments.Text + "')";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Your log has been submitted.");
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Err: " + ex);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

It is giving me a syntax error for the "Date" only. What should I do? I've tried fixing up the properties, making it a short date, general date, etc. Nothing seems to be working for me.

Exact Error:
[image: Error]

Comment: What is the data type of your `Date` on your database ms-access?

Comment: Use parameters to prevent SQLi. Wrap `Date` in `[]` which would become `[Date]` as it's a reserved keyword in your insert into statement. Also if you would have used parameters, this kind of issue wouldn't exist. Also worth mentioning, `It is giving me a syntax error`, that's not descriptive.

Comment: Currently I have it as short date. And while it was on short date, I've tried a variety of different properties on my visual studio date, such as short, and custom (MM/dd/yyyy), while trying ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") and even ToShortDateString()...

Comment: if it is on short date, you shouln't use a `'`(single quote) instead use a hash `#`

Comment: I'll make sure to wrap date in parameters. As for passing through a short date, could you show me an example with the hashtags instead of single quotes?

Comment: `I'll make sure to wrap date in parameters` no, you create parameters that are added to your command, then you don't need any quotes, hashtags etc. and or string concatenation to perform your query. When you do this it's safer and less error prone.

Comment: @zaggler I am trying it out, and I get that it makes it less error prone, though for the date, it still is not working.

Comment: `it still is not working` isn't clear. What isn't working, the insert itself, are any errors etc.? Without details I can't guide you.

Comment: @zaggler Same error as I stated above, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException(0x80040E14): Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement... There seems to be an issue with converting the date I believe, is there any hidden property that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parameterizing your command. This will take care of any potential SQL injection problems as well as correctly formatting the values for the DBMS.

```
string commandText = "insert into DailyLog (EmployeeID,BusNumber,RouteID,DestinationID,ActivityID,Date,MilesDriven,GasInGallons,Comments) values(@employee, @bus, @route, @dest, @activity, @theDate, @miles, @gas, @comments)";

using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection)) {

    // add parameters
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@employee", OleDbType.Integer));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@theDate", OleDbType.DBDate));

    // set parameter valuess
    command.Parameters["@employee"] = employee.SelectedValue;
    command.Parameters["@theDate"] = theDate.Value;

    // execute command
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**Updated to remove AddWithValue.**

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue` it has to infer the data types and it's wrong. You should call `Add` and specify the actual column data type, length and the value.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @Nicholas Hunter you can do `command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@employee", OleDbType.Integer)).Value = employee.SelectedValue;` as well; instead of looking for the parameter again to set its value.

Comment: `new OleDbParameter("@theDate", OleDbType.DBDate) { Value = theDate.Value }`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes oh there are many ways to skin a fish :)

Comment: Just imagine if people put as much effort into answering OP's question as they put into kibbitzing at other people's answers.

Comment: `Just imagine if people put as much effort into answering OP's`, just imagine if some people took useful feedback to improve instead of criticizing constructive feedback. It's all good, it was a suggestion and or another option; it's not saying you're wrong.

Comment: Our comments are intended to help you improve your answer. We just could post an improved answer an earn all the upvotes.

Comment: I am utilizing this answer, and it is still failing for the date...

Comment: @EianKnudsen, add the date as `DateTime` and don't use `.ToString()` if your table column is a date/time.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes as in, ```DateTime myDate = theDate.Value```? Because that is not working. I posted the error above.

Comment: Note that you must not surround parameters by single quotes (not even for string parameters)! Also OleDB ignores the parameter names. They are positional and must appear in the same order as listed before. Also, I asssumed that `theDate` is a `DateTime?` (same as `Nullable<DateTime>`) and that the column also is a date time. Please specify the types of the two and show you updated insert.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Within the Parameters in the '''commandText''', they are not surrounded by single quotes. I made sure. '''theDate''' is from a dateTimePicker. The value should be '''DateTime''', I put it in a variable just incase. I also tried parsing the text value of '''theDate''' as '''DateTime''' to ensure that. In the property of both Microsoft Access and Visual Studio, the dates are both short. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233020/discussion-between-eian-knudsen-and-olivier-jacot-descombes).